# Reference request: QFT and AdS/CFT for information theorists

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-information, ads-cft, holographic-principle

There is a lot of buzz recently about connections between quantum information theory and quantum field theory/string theory. I would like to understand in particular how quantum information methods can be relevant in quantum field theories, string theories, AdS/CFT; and vice-versa, i.e. how to apply high-energy physics techniques in information theory.

I would prefer references which are reasonably elementary and to the point, i.e. addressed to information theorists rather than generically to high-energy physicists.

My background is mostly from an information theory context, but with some good basis knowledge of QFT.